# Populating cells from a different sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a tool that populates a list of parts to be audited from a parts list on the 2nd sheet (PARTS).  The parts are in classes (A, B, or C) so the tool uses a random number generator to select what row to check the part class in. I am getting `1004 runtime error` when I try to check the part class and would appreciate some help getting around this.  Here is the loop that is giving me an error:

```
'While loop to obtain 6 A-Class part numbers to audit
Dim rand As Variant

Do While Acount <= 6
    'Random number generator
    rand = Int((6451 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
    'checking part class ***If statement gives error***
    If Sheets("PARTS").Cells(rand, 5).Value = "A" Then
        Acount = Acount + 1
        'audit list copies cell from parts list
        Sheets("AUDIT POPULATOR").Cells(Acount, 1).Value = Sheets("PARTS").Cells(rand, 1).Value
    Else
        Acount = Acount
        Sheets("AUDIT POPULATOR").Cells(Acount, 1).Value = ""
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: which line does it stop on?

Comment: Is your macro run from the same workbook as Sheets("PARTS")? Does Sheets("PARTS") actually exist? Does it always break, or just with some values of rand?

Comment: The error occurs if I stop it at 'Acount = Acount + 1'
So I think the If statement causes the error

Comment: Yes, the macro is for a command button on the first sheet of the workbook.  the sheet PARTS is what I typed into the tab for the second sheet and it breaks on all values of rand.

Comment: This is a tangent but theoretically the loop could be infinite? I mean, how often does A appear?

Comment: About 3% of the time, that's the percentage of those parts.

Comment: That's cool. I am curious why 6451-2+1. Can't you just do 6450? (I am not good at math.)

Answer (score 0):

because you didnt initialized the 'acount' variable so its empty, hence you get error 1004. also i recommend to use 'option explicit' declaration to prevent such errors. here is your code with the missing parts:

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'While loop to obtain 6 A-Class part numbers to audit
Dim rand As Variant
Dim Acount As Integer
Acount = 1 ' 1 or whatever number you would like to get start...
Do While Acount <= 6
'Random number generator
rand = Int((6451 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
'checking part class ***If statement gives error***
If Sheets("PARTS").Cells(rand, 5).Value = "A" Then
    Acount = Acount + 1
    'audit list copies cell from parts list
    Sheets("AUDIT POPULATOR").Cells(Acount, 1).Value = Sheets("PARTS").Cells(rand, 1).Value
Else
    Acount = Acount
    Sheets("AUDIT POPULATOR").Cells(Acount, 1).Value = ""
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if that's the entirety of his code that he posted. Also if you don't initialize a variable I think it starts at 0 and will still work. Kind of like when you do a for loop with `for i=1`. Rarely is that initialized. I think rand is the issue. He forced it to be an integer but maybe something isn't right there.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, unfortunately I did initialize Acount (as integer, then Acount = 0) I only posted the loop that gave me issues.  I will see if option explicit helps though.

Comment: you are right, but as you said it starts from 0 and there is no 0 row and that`s why there is an error

Comment: lol there you go Diego! Why would you initialize it as 0?! =P

Comment: ....so it was even more of a rookie move than I had expected! Thanks a bunch for the heads up.  I got it to populate the list but sometimes I get an error saying 'subscript out of range'.  I set the random number within the values of the rows populated in the parts list. Any advice?

Comment: We've all been there. Try setting a `debug.print Account` and `debug.print rand` inside the `if statement` then review the immediate window. Should tell you right away what went wrong. Edit: actually place the rand print right below when you set it.

Comment: maybe try to replace the integer value type to long value type for the 'subscript out of range'

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions everyone, the code's running correctly now.  I appreciate the help!